# Update to 13.10 failed via update manager

Tags: updates, system

Update to 13.10 failed via update manager, the failure information as below:

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to disable the CD/DVD entry in: Software Center>Edit menu>Sources

[image]

Comment: after dsiable the